# Holomorphic function $f:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ not being constant in an open set $\Omega$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $\Omega$ an open connected set, and $f:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ holomorphic. I have proved that $f$ is constant.

It is easy to see since if $f=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$ then $v(x,y)=0$ and from the Cauchy-Riemann equations it follows that $u_x,u_y=0$

However, why has $\Omega$ to be connected for $f$ to be constant? I can't think of an example where $\Omega$ is not connected and $f$ is not constant.

Comment: Take $\Omega$ to be the disjoint union of two balls (e.g. $\Omega_1 = B(-1,1/2)$ and $\Omega_2 = B(1,1/2)$; $\Omega = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$).  Set $f(z) = -1$ for $z \in \Omega_1$ and $f(z) = 1$ for $z\in \Omega_2$.  Then $f$ is holomorphic and not constant.

Comment: Because knowledge of $f$ on one component of the domain tells you nothing about the value of $f$ on another component. You only know that $f$ is constant on each component of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Zero derivative implies "locally constant". You need connected to turn this into "globally constant".

Answer (score 0):

Say $\Omega=D(0,1)\cup D(3,1)$, and let $f=0$ on $D(0,1)$,  $f=2$ on $D(3,1)$.